# XSLT Remove Node if a Attribute not match a value

Tags: xml, xslt

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <record>
      <Position>
         <Customer_Cost_EUR>13.218.400.000.000.000</Customer_Cost_EUR>
         t&gt;
         <Charge_Type>cycleCharge</Charge_Type>
         <Customer_Company>GmbH + Co. KG</Customer_Company>
         <Customer_ID>98079</Customer_ID>
         <Kundennummer_customer />
      </Position>
      <Position>
         <Customer_Cost_EUR>23.510.400.000.000.000</Customer_Cost_EUR>
         <Charge_Type>addQuantity</Charge_Type>
         <Customer_ID>98079</Customer_ID>
         <Kundennummer_customer />
      </Position>
      <Position>
         <Customer_Cost_EUR>0</Customer_Cost_EUR>
         <Charge_Type>new</Charge_Type>
         <Customer_ID>98079</Customer_ID>
         <Kundennummer_customer />
      </Position>
   </record>
   <record>
      <Position>
         <Customer_Cost_EUR>23.510.400.000.000.000</Customer_Cost_EUR>
         <Charge_Type>addQuantity</Charge_Type>
         <Customer_ID>98079</Customer_ID>
         <Kundennummer_customer />
      </Position>
      <Position>
         <Customer_Cost_EUR>23.510.400.000.000.000</Customer_Cost_EUR>
         <Charge_Type>worktime</Charge_Type>
         <Customer_ID>98079</Customer_ID>
         <Kundennummer_customer />
      </Position>
   </record>
</root>
```

Now i want to remove all Position that not macht the Charge_Type 'new', 'renew' or 'cycleCharge'

This is my goal:

```html
<root>
<record>
      <Position>
         <Customer_Cost_EUR>13.218.400.000.000.000</Customer_Cost_EUR>t>
         <Charge_Type>cycleCharge</Charge_Type>
         <Customer_Company>GmbH + Co. KG</Customer_Company>
         <Customer_ID>98079</Customer_ID>
         <Kundennummer_customer/>
      </Position>
      <Position>
         <Customer_Cost_EUR>0</Customer_Cost_EUR>
         <Charge_Type>new</Charge_Type>
         <Customer_ID>98079</Customer_ID>
         <Kundennummer_customer/>
      </Position>
   </record>
   <record>
      <Position>
         <Customer_Cost_EUR>10</Customer_Cost_EUR>
         <Charge_Type>renew</Charge_Type>
         <Customer_ID>98018</Customer_ID>
         <Kundennummer_customer/>
      </Position>
   </record>
 </root>
```

if there is no Position node left, then the record node should also be removed

However I cannot find any articles that demonstrate how to do this in xsl so I would be very greatful if someone could provide me with an example or link me an article that explains how to do this. Thanks in advance.

I have two XSLT Flies and it works. But how can i Combine the two files in on File together with the same result?

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Position[Charge_Type!='renew' and Charge_Type!='new'  and Charge_Type!='cycleCharge'  ]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>



<!-- And the second XSLT -->



<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="record[not(descendant::Customer_ID)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: `Charge_Type` is not an attribute!

Answer (score 3):

I think this will do what you want:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
  
<xsl:template match="Position[Charge_Type!='renew' and Charge_Type!='new' and Charge_Type!='cycleCharge']"/>

<xsl:template match="record[not(Position/Charge_Type='renew' or Position/Charge_Type='new' or Position/Charge_Type='cycleCharge')]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this as the test input XML:

```
<root>
    <record>
        <Position>
            <Charge_Type>cycleCharge</Charge_Type>
            <Customer_ID>100</Customer_ID>
        </Position>
        <Position>
            <Charge_Type>addQuantity</Charge_Type>
            <Customer_ID>101</Customer_ID>
        </Position>
        <Position>
            <Charge_Type>new</Charge_Type>
            <Customer_ID>102</Customer_ID>
        </Position>
    </record>
    <record>
        <Position>
            <Charge_Type>renew</Charge_Type>
            <Customer_ID>201</Customer_ID>
        </Position>
        <Position>
            <Charge_Type>addQuantity</Charge_Type>
            <Customer_ID>202</Customer_ID>
        </Position>
    </record>
    <record>
        <Position>
            <Charge_Type>addQuantity</Charge_Type>
            <Customer_ID>301</Customer_ID>
        </Position>
        <Position>
            <Charge_Type>worktime</Charge_Type>
            <Customer_ID>302</Customer_ID>
        </Position>
    </record>
</root>
```

my result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
   <record>
      <Position>
         <Charge_Type>cycleCharge</Charge_Type>
         <Customer_ID>100</Customer_ID>
      </Position>
      <Position>
         <Charge_Type>new</Charge_Type>
         <Customer_ID>102</Customer_ID>
      </Position>
   </record>
   <record>
      <Position>
         <Charge_Type>renew</Charge_Type>
         <Customer_ID>201</Customer_ID>
      </Position>
   </record>
</root>
```

Comment: Here ist the result. The last Record Tag is still there!

Comment: <Charge_Type>renew</Charge_Type>
         <Customer_ID>98018</Customer_ID>
         <Kundennummer_customer/>
      </Position>
   </record>
   <record/>
</root>

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in the last template. Try it now.

Answer (score -2):

Try a powershell script

Here is my results

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <record>
    <Position>
      <Customer_Cost_EUR>13.218.400.000.000.000</Customer_Cost_EUR>t&gt;
      <Charge_Type>cycleCharge</Charge_Type><Customer_Company>Tepass Schwelm GmbH + Co. KG</Customer_Company><Customer_ID>98079</Customer_ID><Kundennummer_customer /></Position>
    <Position>
      <Customer_Cost_EUR>0</Customer_Cost_EUR>
      <Charge_Type>new</Charge_Type>
      <Customer_ID>98079</Customer_ID>
      <Kundennummer_customer />
    </Position>
  </record>
  <record>
    <Position>
      <Customer_Cost_EUR>10</Customer_Cost_EUR>
      <Charge_Type>renew</Charge_Type>
      <Customer_ID>98018</Customer_ID>
      <Kundennummer_customer />
    </Position>
  </record>
</root>
```

Here is script

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$inputFilename = 'c:\temp\test.xml'
$outputFilename = 'c:\temp\test1.xml'

$xDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)
$records = $xDoc.Descendants('record').Foreach([System.Xml.Linq.XElement])

for($i = ($records.Count) - 1; $i -ge 0; $i--)
{
   $record = $records[$i]
   $filteredRecords = @([System.Linq.Enumerable]::Where($record.Elements('Position'),  [Func[object,bool]]{ param($x) ($x[0].Element('Charge_Type').Value -eq 'new') -or ($x[0].Element('Charge_Type').Value -eq 'renew') -or ($x[0].Element('Charge_Type').Value -eq 'cycleCharge')}))

   If($filteredRecords.Count -eq 0) { $record.Remove() }`
   Else { $record.RemoveAll(); $record.Add($filteredRecords) }
}

$xDoc.Save($outputFilename)
```

Comment: sorry I Need a XSLT